# Excel combind multiple columns with : and ; between each value pair

Tags: excel, formula, vba

excel formula like this

```
=$C$1&":"&C2&";"&$D$1&":"&D2&";"&$E$1&E2
```

Result

```
US:2.27;AU:2.05;BR2.95
```

I want to do a long formula from column C to W. How do I speed up writing the formula or using VBA?

```
     C      D       E                F
1    US     AU      BR     combined_countryshipping
2    2.27   2.05    2.95   US:2.27;AU:2.05;BR2.95
```

This is only 3 countries for example. I have 40-50 countries to combine.

Comment: in VBA you would set up a loop that would repeat util you reach a condition.  For Loop, or While Loops would work

Comment: Do you have `TEXTJOIN()`? Also why 'suddenly' do you do `E1&E2`? Will that be a repetitive issue, or will some need that, and there's no real pattern to know which ones?

Comment: Dang it, I can never suggest that option as I never get to use it with my version of excel @BruceWayne

Comment: $C$1& each of these are country codes and the numbers are shipping costs. I have hundreds of rows to combine columns in each row into last column in a row.

Comment: Can you post some sample data, and the expected output?

Comment: @ForwardEd - It's almost worth the upgrade to get that alone, it's so useful! But of course, there's always just making your own UDF (see Scott's answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may give this a try...

```
Function CustomConcatenate(ByVal Rng As Range) As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim str As String
For Each cell In Rng
    If cell.Row = Rng.Cells(1).Row Then
        If str = "" Then
            str = cell & ":" & cell.Offset(1, 0)
        Else
            str = str & ";" & cell & ":" & cell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next cell
CustomConcatenate = str
End Function
```

And then try it on the sheet like this...

```
=CustomConcatenate(C1:W2)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 Excel then you can use TEXTJOIN in an array formula:

Put this in F2:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,$C$1:$E$1&":"&C2:E2)
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Put in F2.  Hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter then copy/drag down the length.

[image]

---

If you sometimes have blanks in the values and want to skip the country in the output when it is blank use this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(";",TRUE,IF(C2:E2<>"",$C$1:$E$1&":"&C2:E2,""))
```

This will skip any countries with blank values.

---

If you do not have TEXTJOIN you can put this in a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Scott. I just tried your code by putting it in excel vba. It works on the first row but when I drag down the results are the same as the first row. The row number in the F2 changes accordingly but the results are the same as in the first row. Any editing needed?

Comment: =TEXTJOIN(":",TRUE,IF(C2:E2<>"",$C$1:$E$1&":"&C2:E2,""))   This one misses the ; before country code. Could you correct it? Thanks.

Comment: Did you drag the formula down, or did you paste the formula into each cell individually?

Comment: The first `:` should be `;`  I edited the answer to fix.

Comment: Hi Scott. The drag down works now. I just changed the workbook calculation from Manual to Automatic. Thanks a lot.